# Should I standardize first or generate polynomials first?

Tags: classification, data-preprocessing

Recently I am dealing a classification problem with some algorithms, say logistic regression.

When I preprocess my data, I standardize all my features and generate polynomial features based on them first.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures, StandardScaler
```

and I do

```
features = std.fit_transform(features)
features = poly.fit_transform(features)
```

After finishing training my model, the accuracy is, say about 80%. Then I invert the two line of preprocessing code to

```
# features is my entire features dataset, labels excluded 
features = poly.fit_transform(features)
features = std.fit_transform(features)
```

It gives a slightly better result on accuracy.

I have read [this post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/9020/do-i-have-to-standardize-my-new-polynomial-features) but it seems the answers is not strong enough to help me figure it out.

Should I standardize my data first or generate polynomials from original features first? Is there any kind of "best practice" should I follow in general?

I understand answers to this question may vary depending on the dataset, so let's assume I am using a dataset similar to the famous Iris dataset but with about 20 features and 1000 samples.

Comment: As to the post you refer to, could you add what you are missing? i.e. why isn't it strong enough to answer your question?

Comment: @IWS Since I tested on five different dataset and the results varied. Some of them are fit to "generate polynomials first" better and others stand at the opposite... little confused...

Comment: Well, IMO the choices you make during preprocessing should not depend on the final result. Moreover, finding a better fit in certain data does not mean it is a better way of doing things. It could also mean you've overfitted your data and created a too optimistic model which will generalize poorly to other (unseen) data. Anyway, in your case I'd say generating polynomials first and standardizing afterwards is best because all final variables are actually the standardized version of what they supposed to represent, instead of the polynomial of a data-dependent standardization.

Comment: I would say best practise is transform (using nonlinearities first) then standardise.  However, I believe that in the *special case of polynomials* it perhaps doesn't make a difference - what is mean and variance of transformed normalised variables? also note that standardisation is *potentially* beneficial only for *penalised* logistic regression not for unpenalised.

Comment: @IWS Thx, I understand the problem of overfitting, so I tested on a part of samples the model has never seen during the training. Thanks for your tips.

Comment: @seanv507 I think I need some time to experiment about the relation between the "result" and "mean and variance of transformed variables". I like your *highlighted* idea :D and many thx to you.

Comment: @sean The order can make a *huge* difference. Consider a regressor $x$ with values varying between $1$ and $1000$. In a third-order polynomial model, $x^3$ will vary between $1$ and $10^9$, whence the variation among entries in $X^\prime X$ ($X$ is the design matrix) will cover 18 orders of magnitude, making its inversion unstable using floating point arithmetic. Even procedures that do not explicitly perform this calculation will suffer comparable problems. Standardizing $x$ at the outset eliminates this difficulty.

Comment: @whuber This is a very appropriate example, many thanks.

Comment: @whuber, I was ignoring numerical stability, but am not clear about your reasoning: the X matrix is normalised, and AFAIK ill conditioning is only due to large differences in eigenvalues of $X'X$ or correlation matrix in this case.

Comment: @sean If `sklearn` does standardize all variables automatically, that's worth knowing if you're going to use it, but it doesn't really address the general question that has been raised. It turns out that standardizing $X$ is not routine in all statistical platforms. Most ML solvers I have looked at in `R`, for instance, don't do that. Indeed, to claim "the X matrix is normalized" seems tantamount to avoiding the question, because it is asserting that standardization is always going to occur as the last step before executing the model fitting procedure.

Comment: @whuber, sorry I was just talking in the context of the OP's question: whether it is better to standardise then polynomial transform or transform and then standardise *before model fitting*- I agree that most packages and sklearn don't standardise by default. [glmnet is one that does]